# Get the value of a class field from string in php

Tags: php

I have a class question. I'm extending other classes from this one. Lets say that in my new class that is extending Base I set the field $key="two". Now, the value of $this->two is the primary key I would use to find/replace/update rows in the database.

I want to be able to call a save function. To do this I will need to know what that key value is. How would I get the value of $this->two by my field $key being equal to "two"?

I'm asking because depending on the class that extends Base, the key won't always be two, it may be one or three.

In this example, I have a method getKeyValue showing what I would like to do.

```
class Base{

    public $table, $class, $key;
    public $one, $two, $three;

    public function __construct()
    {
      $this->class="" . __CLASS__;
          $this->key="user_id";
    }
    public function __destruct()
    {
      //echo 'The class "', __CLASS__, '" was destroyed.<br />';
    }

    public function __toString()
    {

      return "Cannot output Base Class as a string";
    }
    public function getKeyValue(){
        return $this->$key;

    }
}
```

Comment: `$this->{$this->key}`

Comment: why go through all this indirection? your sub-objects' constructors should just store the appropriate value in a single fixed key, e.g. `function __construct() { $this->key = 'two' }`, then it's `$this->key` regardless of which particular instance you're dealing with.

Comment: @ClémentMalet: Yes, read right past it.